# IIS Razor site deployment error with local db

Tags: c#, sql-server, razor

My razor website gives this error and wouldn't proceed. What's wrong?

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Error occurred during LocalDB instance startup: SQL Server process failed to start.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your web server doesn't have the localDB engine installed on it. Are you using shared hosting? Might want to check with your hosting provider to see what database services they provide.